# "Launch Application" and "Quit Application" keywords are not working on iOS 15.5, appium - 1.22.3, and robotframework - 1.6.3

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, ios15

**XCode version:** 13.4.1

**Appium version:** 1.22.3

**robotframework-appiumlibrary version:** 1.6.3

**Appium-Python-Client:** 1.3.0

**iPhone and iOS:** iPhone 8 and iOS 15.5

`Launch Application` and `Quit Application` keywords are getting executed successfully but these keyword's effect is no more seen on the mobile phone with the above environment setup

On appium version <= 1.21.0, `Launch Application` and `Quit Application` keywords are working as expected.

`Go Back` keyword is also not working !

I want to "Relaunch" my iOS app, Is there any other way that can be performed and can be integrated with Robot Framework script ?

Suggestion: All python-appium library keywords should be accessible by robotframework-appium library keywords (For ex. "Terminate App" and "Launch App" combination resolves my issue for relaunching the app. "Terminate App" keyword is not available in robotframework-appium)

Note - Above mentioned keywords are working as expected for Android platform. Seems like there might issue between XCode and Appium v1.22.3 (As this bridge is only having the issue, maybe both are not compatible with each other)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue since I have upgrade Appium to v1.22.3. Close Application or Close All Applications are not working anymore. With v1.21.0, the issue is not present, but this version of Appium doesn't handle iOS 15.
You can create a custom keyword in Python to solve the issue.

```
from appium import webdriver

def terminate_appcustom(version,deviceName,udid,bundleId):
    caps = {}
    caps["appium:platformVersion"] = version
    caps["appium:deviceName"] = deviceName
    caps["appium:udid"] = udid
    caps["appium:instrumentApp"] = "true"
    caps["appium:bundleId"] = bundleId
    caps["platformName"] = "ios"
    caps["appium:includeSafariInWebviews"] = True
    caps["appium:newCommandTimeout"] = 3600
    caps["appium:connectHardwareKeyboard"] = True
    driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", caps)
    driver.terminate_app(bundleId)
```